# Limiting per process dirty bytes without slowing down the whole system

Tags: linux, performance, io, scheduling, limit

Given a busy system with a really fast block device (highend NVMe raid, 2 GB/s write, 4 GB/s read) mounted at `/data` and an a really slow device (USB HDD with spinning 8 TB disk, 50 MB/s write, 60 MB/s read) mounted at `/backup`, how can I limit processes reading from and writing to `/backup` without sacrificing I/O of `/data`?

As far as I know, the problem is that linux only has **global** knobs `dirty_background_bytes` and `dirty_bytes`. If I set those limits to sensible values for NVMe (around 2 GB and 4 GB in practice) the throughput is fine until a process (e.g. `rsync`) starts to write to USB with lots of data. In that case `dirty_background` is filled with data going to USB device and `rsync` is stopped from dirtying more pages. However, that causes processes writing to fast devices to be aggressively slowed down because `dirty_background` is global limit and shared between fast and slow devices. I know that I can limit dirty bytes according to **slowest** device connected to the system and that will avoid huge stalls but will sacrifice some throughput of the faster devices.

**Is there equivalent of `dirty_background_bytes` for a single block device?** It really makes zero sense to slow down *all* processes writing to `/data` in case `/backup` is slow and accessed by some other process.

I know that `cgroup` can be used to do this manually ([How to Throttle per process I/O to a max limit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit)). However, I would like to adjust this per block device and all processes accessing said devices should be throttled down before slowing down the whole system. If a process writes to both fast and slow devices, it should get slowed down only if it's writing too much to the slow device.

Comment: Possibly the thing I'm looking for is /sys/class/bdi/*/max_ratio - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338317/20336 for more info.

Comment: The `bdi` interface requires major:minor info. It can be figured out with `findmnt` and `lsblk`. Note that in case of RAID, one mount point can be backed by multiple devices.

Comment: I think the `bdi` settings are not as effective as you hoped for, and will not really protect you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481356/29483

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714267/20336