# How to limit IO bandwidth using systemd?

Tags: systemd, io, bandwidth

I'm trying to limit IO usage of a service (or process/command). (Limit for IO read/write on hardware device, not for network.)

I found IOAccounting from systemd:

```
systemd-run --scope --user -p "IOReadBandwidthMax=/dev/zero 1M" -p "IOAccounting=true" \
    time dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100M of=/tmp/foo conv=fdatasync

systemd-run --scope --user -p "IOWriteBandwidthMax=/dev/sdd 1M" -p "IOAccounting=true" \
    time dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100M of=/tmp/foo conv=fdatasync
```

The command ends quickly and report 200/300 MB/s. Exactly the same results when I run the command, without systemd-run wrapper.

I tried also to write the systemd service, without systemd-run: IO bandwidth limitation is not working.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: Thank you for the reponse.
sudo made the trick.
I failed also to limit read/write from or to a encrypted device. /tmp was in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your test for system's `systemd` (root authentication required) shows that the IO limit is working, it takes 10 seconds:

```
systemd-run --scope -p IOWriteBandwidthMax='/dev/sda 10M' time dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100M of=/tmp/foo conv=fdatasync
```

Running for user's `systemd` the limit is not working, because IO cannot be controlled by default by users. The Arch wiki has a useful bit for this:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/cgroups#As_unprivileged_user

There is a proposal to use delegation for a user service. Also for any process, the control groups can be used (like into this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit)) and again it is not directly available for user to control IO and set limits.