# How to reduce Linux' write buffer for removable devices?

Tags: buffer, removable-storage

When writing content to removable devices on Linux (USB sticks/HDDs, SD cards, etc), I often see incredible write speeds in the first few seconds, sometimes in the order of GB/s (filling of the write buffer) followed by several minutes of quiet (buffer actually being written to the device).

It's misleading. It makes it hard to judge the actual write speed. It's annoying (can't interrupt a program while it's flushing buffers). It can cause FS damage, and at the very least unwritten content when the device is unplugged while it's still being written.

The write buffer appears to be over a GB in my case. Is there a way to control it? I'd like to reduce it to a more sensible value.

Note: This is not about filesystem cache, this effect also appears on raw devices

Note: I do not want to disable write buffers entirely

Thanks!

Comment: never unplug the removable device without `umount`ing an fs (in GUI use 'eject' button on mounted fs node in the tree shown by file manager). The `umount` effectively completes any pending IO and flushes any outstanding fs cashes.

Comment: (and when writing the device directly e.g. with `dd`, you must make sure to use something like `sync` before you remove the device)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer. 64-bit Linux maintains a large write buffer (20% of available memory!) by default. (Interestingly, 32-bit Linux limits itself to at most 180MB) To change the dirty buffer size to e.g. 200MB, one can use

```
echo 200000000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

**OR** to use a percentage of RAM, e.g. 1%:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
```

More information: https://lwn.net/Articles/572911/

Comment: Both 32-bit and 64-bit Linux kernels use default `dirty_ratio` of 20. However, 32-bit kernel has maximum available kernel RAM limit of 1 GB due to limits of 32-bit x86 architecture. As a result, maximum default write cache size on 32-bit system is around 180-200 MB depending on hardware (at least PCI devices with DMA access will reduce usable RAM limit).

Comment: This isn't the complete answer to your original question though. I want to throttle my external slow storage, not my internal fast storage...

Comment: Decreasing the write_buffer size below the current utilization may lead to a somewhat unresponsive system, as it appears new writes are blocked until space is available in the cache, which is now overfull. Creating a directory in this state has left me enough time to clean up a kid's toys in the yard, cut a slice of key lime cheesecake and a glass of milk, and finish both while I write this from my phone.

Comment: After using low `dirty_bytes` setting (200 MB) for a longer time, I've noticed that using single global limit is pretty bad because slow device can still fill the buffer and then writes to another fast SSD device suffers as a result. The correct fix is to apply device specific limit but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do that. I think optimal setting would be 200 MB per device for my case.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714267/20336